# Why does running an animation in the Godot editor affect game state?

Tags: animation, godot

There is an animation on an enemy in the demo project "Platformer 2D (Raycasting)".  If you run the destroy animation in the editor, it will mess with how the enemies behave in game.  Here is the animation:
[image]

If you run all the way through (leaving the keyframe position at the end of destroy), then hit "Play", the enemies will all no longer exist.  If you leave the keyframe position at the beginning, it will still affect which collision_layer the enemy is on, making it so they no longer collide with anything.

**How and why is this happening?  And how does one make it stop?**

Answer (score 1):

More info here:  https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/3829

It turns out that animations in earlier versions of Godot just changed the settings, with no way to fall back to what they were.  For this reason, people would make "RESET" tracks which would reset everything.  It was kind of a hassle, so the automatic creation of them was introduced, but it does not retro-actively affect projects.

My issue was running an older project, and it's issue was that it didn't have a RESET track.